# Why this ng-repeat does not loop all the values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Even more values are pushed into the array:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.mottos = [];
  $scope.mottos.push('One');
  $scope.mottos.push('Two');

  $scope.addMotto = function(motto) {
    $scope.mottos.push(motto);
  }    
});
```

and

```
<span ng-repeat="motto in mottos"> {{motto}} </span>
```

ng-repeat does not show all elements as expect: [codepen](http://codepen.io/ohho/pen/bdRKER), why?
    ...

HTML

```
<ion-content>

    <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="addMotto('More')">
      <i class="icon ion-quote"> Click me to add more ...</i>
    </button>

    <div class="card item-text-wrap">
     <div class="item">
      {{mottos.length}}
      <span ng-repeat="motto in mottos"> {{motto}} </span>
     </div>
    </div>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: `<span ng-repeat="motto in mottos"> {{motto}} </span>` is repeated 2 times with values `One` & `Two`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Try hitting the "add more" button a few times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
 <span ng-repeat="motto in mottos"> {{motto}} </span>
```

try something like this

```
 <span ng-repeat="motto in mottos track by $index"> {{motto}} </span>
```

you can see this in more detail on [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) page

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> By default, `ngRepeat` does not allow duplicate items in arrays. This
>   is because when there are duplicates, it is not possible to maintain a
>   one-to-one mapping between collection items and DOM elements.
>
> If you do need to repeat duplicate items, you can substitute the
>   default tracking behavior with your own using the `track by`
>   expression.

So if you update your code as follows, things work as expected:

```
<span ng-repeat="motto in mottos track by $index">
    {{motto}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue occurs because `ng-repeat` does not have a unique identifier for each object. If you change the code to append the length on each object (more1, more2, more3, etc since lengths/indexes are unique) it works fine. I've seen a similar issue in WPF.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I'm a bit confused on why this doesn't answer the question. If you add a unique id to the object, then it works perfectly. Here's an example in codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJEYwv. The changes are as follows: name the original field 'name' and add an id (unqiue identifier), bind to name.

Answer (score 1):

because you need to use `$track by`
he solution is actually described here: http://www.anujgakhar.com/2013/06/15/duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed-in-angularjs/

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doRKWY

```
<span ng-repeat="motto in mottos track by $index"> {{motto}} </span>
```